# NuSoap Complex type when count + array of results

Tags: php, nusoap

I need some help implementing a php nusoap responce.

Here is what my function returns

```
Array
(
    [total] => 8177
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 340
                    [name] => Hamburg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 344
                    [name] => Fos
                )
         )
)
```

Now i need to return this as an xml. No matter what I tried ( basically guess ) i get

```
<total xsi:type="xsd:int">8177</total>
    <results xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[1000]">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:">
            <id xsi:type="xsd:string">340</id>
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string">Hamburg</name>
        </item>
```

as you can see `SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[1000]">` ( empty before the : ) also `<item xsi:type="xsd:">` and all my items are types string/string .

Here I will post my code so far hopefully someone can spot the problem.

```
$server->register(
                "tankerPortsSearch",
                [
                    'name' => 'xsd:string',
                    'step' => 'xsd:int',
                    'page' => 'xsd:int',
                ],
                [
                    'total'   => 'xsd:int',
                    'results' => 'tns:responceArray'
                ],
                'urn:tankerPortsSearch',
                'urn:tankerZonesTraffic#tankerPortsSearch',
                'rpc',
                'encoded',
                'Tanker Ports Search'
            );


            $server->wsdl->addComplexType('responceArrayData', 'complexType', 'struct', '', 'SOAP-ENC:Array', [
                'id'   => array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
                'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
            ]);
            // *************************************************************************

            // Complex Array ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            $server->wsdl->addComplexType('responceArray', 'complexType', 'array', 'squence', '', [], [
                [
                    'ref'            => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
                    'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:responceArrayData[]'
                ]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after hours of back and forward I manage to guess the right response, I will post it here in case someone else is stuck with nusoap complex types

```
$server->register("tankerPortsSearch", [
        'name' => 'xsd:string',
        'step' => 'xsd:int',
        'page' => 'xsd:int',
    ], [
        'total'   => 'xsd:int',
        'results' => 'tns:responceArray'
    ], 'urn:tankerPortsSearch', 'urn:tankerZonesTraffic#tankerPortsSearch', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Tanker Ports Search');


$server->wsdl->addComplexType('responceArrayData', 'complexType', 'struct', '', '', [
    'id'   => array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'name' => array('name' => 'name', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
]);
// *************************************************************************

// Complex Array ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('responceArray', 'complexType', 'array', '', '', [], [
    [
        'ref'            => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
        'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:responceArrayData[]',
    ]
], 'tns:responceArrayData');
```

Hopefully i managed to help someone.

Cheers